# Reverse inheritance mapping in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have a three tables:

**Domain**

```
|Field   |Type         |
| id     | BIGINT      |
| domain | VARVHAR(45) |
| other  | ...         |
```

**Url**

```
|Field      |Type         |
| id        | BIGINT      |
| domain_id | BIGINT      |
| url       | VARCHAR(45) |
| other     | ...         |
```

**Data**

```
|Field      |Type                  |
| id        | BIGINT               |
| type      | ENUM('DOMAIN','URL') |
| entity_id | BIGINT               |
| data      | ...                  |
```

Under *other* fields, witch contains in **Domain** and **Url** tables I understand the some fields, whitch different between themselves by types.

Field *entity_id* in the **Data** table must contain the ID from the table **Domain** or **Url** depending on value of *type* fields in the **Data** table.

How I can create this xml mapping for Hibernate use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for my opinion, you'd better use `@Inheritence` and map the `Data` table with the parent entity like below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="MODEL")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="entity_type",discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Model{

@Id
private int id;
//other common attributes
//getters& setters
}
```

then your `Domain` and `Url` classes

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="domain")
public class Domain extends Model{
private String domain;
//getters&setters
}
```

//

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="url")
public class Url extends Model{
@ManyToOne
private Domain domain;

private String url;
//getters & setters
}
```

and this will create a table named `MODEL` which will have 2 types (`Domain` & `Url`) with an extra column (`entity_type`) which will take as a value `"domain"` or `"url"` depending on the record type.

later in your Data Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Data{
private int id;
@ManyToOne
private Model model;
}
```

Ps: you dont need to add **`type`** attribute in `Data` entity anymore while you have the discreminator column **`entity_type`**